# Declaring a £ sign

Tags: symbols

I have inherited some latex files and they compile fine except for the following line

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\£}{\text{\pounds}}
```

I have deleted the line (and replaced £ with pounds where £ was used) and everything is fine.
But I am curious - presumably the file used to compile?  The line of code also appears to be in all approx 50 files I have inherited so I would like to "correct" rather than "delete" if possible.

Comment: `£` is not a one byte character in UTF-8, so you *can't* use it that way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I have a question: are you sure that you really want to define a “math operator”?  I mean, look closely at the space after the various instances of the “£” character in the following three examples: `$\mathpound(x)$`, `$\mathpound x$`, and `$\mathpound\mathpound x$` (assuming that `\mathpound` is defined as in @egreg’s answer).  Are they OK for you?  (Those that you’ll see are the spaces (La)TeX puts after a “math operator” in those three contexts.)

Answer (score 6):

This works OK when UTF-8 input is not involved. Probably the files you inherited assumed a different input encoding.

Converting them to UTF-8 makes `£` into a two-byte character and `\DeclareMathOperator` doesn't like `\£`.

You *could* do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mathpound}{\textup{\pounds}}
\def\£{\mathpound}

\begin{document}

$\£(x)$

\end{document}
```

but my advice is to give up with `\£` and choose a better name for the command.

Don't try to do something like `\def\µ{...}` along with that code: only one two-byte character with first byte `0xC2` can be used that way.

Comment: Looks like "correcting" will be hard work so I will delete!